# How to change estimote beacon UUID using AndroidSDK

Tags: android, estimote

I'm trying to change the UUID of the estimote beacons and have not found a specific API for this, anyone have any example or help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have, It's the same for the proximityUUID but you gotta change the `writeMajor` by `writeProximityUuid`.

```
private void setMajorID(final int majorid,final Beacon beacon) {

        mMajorsConnection = new BeaconConnection(this, beacon, new BeaconConnection.ConnectionCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthenticated(BeaconConnection.BeaconCharacteristics chars) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Authenticated to beacon: " + chars);
                mMajorsConnection.writeMajor(majorid, new BeaconConnection.WriteCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess() {
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                mAdapter.update(beacon);
                            }
                        });
                        Log.d(TAG, "Successfully writted the major id!");
                        mMajorsConnection.close();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError() {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Error while writting the major id!");
                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void onAuthenticationError() {
                Log.d(TAG, "Authentication Error");
            }

            @Override
            public void onDisconnected() {
                Log.d(TAG, "Disconnected");
            }
        });
            mMajorsConnection.authenticate();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [writeProximityUuid](http://estimote.github.io/Android-SDK/JavaDocs/) method of the `BeaconConnection` class.

Comment: Sure there is an example right here http://estimote.github.io/Android-SDK/JavaDocs/ in the left pane click BeaconConnection it shows you how to get a connection and go from there